# Returning table with varying number of column (dynamically) from a stored procedure without updating edmx

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Suppose I have a SQL stored procedure in which the number of returned columns has to be modified occasionally (in the procedure code).

I want to know how this is handled in entityfrmewok when above mentioned change in procedure occurs without manually updating the *.edmx* file in entity framework.

Below given is the function in which this change has to be handled.

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<usp_GetTimesheetReport_Result> usp_GetTimesheetReport(Nullable<long> userID, Nullable<System.DateTime> pPEDate)
    {
        var userIDParameter = userID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", userID) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserID", typeof(long));

        var pPEDateParameter = pPEDate.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("PPEDate", pPEDate) :
            new ObjectParameter("PPEDate", typeof(System.DateTime));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_GetTimesheetReport_Result>("usp_GetTimesheetReport", userIDParameter, pPEDateParameter);
    }
```

Below is the model used : **usp_GetTimesheetReport_Result**

```
public partial class usp_GetTimesheetReport_Result
{
    public long EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ppedate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime workdate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> signedontime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Shift1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Shift1OT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Shift2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Shift2OT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> shift3 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Shift3OT { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> shift4 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Shift4OT { get; set; }
}
```

The procedure may return columns which may not present in the above model. I tried by giving dynamic object instead if this custom model, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: Off-topic, but did you know you can write `Nullable<type>` simply as `type?` and that by adding a simple `using System;` to your code you can write `System.DateTime` simply as `DateTime`? It helps to make your code more readable.

Comment: @oerkelens thank you for that tip. I'll make that change.